# How to prevent people from spamming an ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problem is I have a vote system similar to the one of Stack Overflow. My problem is that a person can spam the vote up button which makes it glitch and make it submit more times than it’s supposed to. For example, if there are 10 up votes on a post, I could repeatedly click the vote up button and the it would add two or three up votes instead of one. Similarly I could do this with the down vote button. How do I prevent this?

Index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('db.php');
$pid = 2;
$uid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid = '$pid'"); //check to see how many likes the post has
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$body = $r['body'];
$likes = $r['likes'];
$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE pid = '$pid' AND uid = '$uid'");      //check to see if user has voted
$n = mysqli_num_rows($sql2);
if ($n == 0) {
    //user hasn't liked or down vote anything yet
    $liked = "no";
} else {
    if ($n > 1) {
        //like scammed
        echo "<script>alert('Stop spamming for votes. You are banned for spam.')</script>";
        exit("You have been banned for spam");
        //This isn't fool proof though, and I don't want to ban people for this. It would be best if I could just prevent the vote scam in the first place
    }
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);
$type = $r['like_type'];
if ($type == '0') {
    $liked = "liked";
} else {
    $liked = "disliked";
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .selected {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="post">
    <p><?php echo $body; ?></p>
</div>
<div class="likes">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="upvote <?php if ($liked == 'liked') {echo "selected";} ?>" id='up-<?php echo $pid; ?>' onclick="vote('up', '<?php echo $pid; ?>', '<?php echo $uid; ?>', 'up-<?php echo $pid; ?>', 'votes-<?php echo $pid; ?>')">Upvote</a>
    <span id="votes-<?php echo $pid; ?>"><?php echo $likes; ?></span>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="downvote <?php if ($liked == 'disliked') {echo "selected";} ?>" id='down-<?php echo $pid; ?>' onclick="vote('down', '<?php echo $pid; ?>', '<?php echo $uid; ?>', 'down-<?php echo $pid; ?>', 'votes-<?php echo $pid; ?>')">Downvote</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript vote() function

```
function vote(type, pid, uid, id, voteId) {
var vote = $('#'+ id);
if (vote.hasClass('selected')) {
    //user voted for this
    $.post("vote.php", {pid: pid, uid: uid, type: type, vote: 'reset'}, function(d) {
        if (d == '0' || d == '1') {
            vote.removeClass('selected');
            var votes = $('#' + voteId);
            var num = votes.text();
            if (d == '1') {
                votes.text(++num);  
            } else {
                votes.text(--num);
            }
        } else {
            alert('An error occurred')
        }
    });
} else {
    var upVoteId = $('#up-' + pid);
    var downVoteId = $('#down-' + pid);
    if (upVoteId.hasClass('selected') || downVoteId.hasClass('selected')) {
        //user wants to switch votes
        $.post('vote.php', {pid: pid, uid: uid, type: type, vote: 'switch'}, function(data) {
            var votes = $('#' + voteId);
            var num = votes.text();
            if (data == '1') {
                //downvote successful
                votes.text(parseInt(num) - 2);
                vote.addClass('selected');
                upVoteId.removeClass('selected');
            }
            if (data == '0') {
                //upvote successful
                votes.text(parseInt(num) + 2);
                vote.addClass('selected');
                downVoteId.removeClass('selected');
            }
            if (d == 'error') {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $.post('test2.php', {type: type, pid: pid, uid: uid}, function(d) {
            if (d == "1") {
                //everything good
                $('#' + type + '-<?php echo $pid; ?>').addClass('selected');
                var votes = $("#" + voteId).text();
                if (type == 'down') {
                    //downvote
                    votes = --votes;
                    $('#' + voteId).text(votes);
                } else {
                    votes = ++votes;
                    $('#' + voteId).text(votes);
                }
            } else {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    }
}
}
}
```

Vote.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require('db.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['un'])) {
    //not logged in
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
} else {
    if (!isset($_POST['uid'], $_POST['pid'], $_POST['type'], $_POST['vote'])) {
        //form not submitted
        header('Location: home.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        $uid = (int)$_SESSION['id'];
        $pid = (int)$_POST['pid'];
        $type = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['type']);
        $vote = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '',$_POST['vote']); //vote type

        if ($vote == 'reset') {
            //initiate vote reset
            if ($type == 'down') {
                //downvote
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM likes WHERE like_type = '1' AND pid = '$pid' AND uid = '$uid'"); //delete the downvote
                $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE pid = '$pid'");
                if ($sql) {
                    echo "1"; // 1
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo "error";
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                //upvote
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM likes WHERE like_type = '0' AND pid = '$pid' AND uid = '$uid'"); //delete upvote
                $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes - 1 WHERE pid = '$pid'");
                if ($sql) {
                    echo "0"; // 0
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo "error";
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($vote == 'switch') {
            //user wanted to switch vote
            if ($type == 'down') {
                //user had voted up but wants to vote down now
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM likes WHERE like_type = '0' AND pid = '$pid' AND uid = '$uid'"); //delete the previous vote
                $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO likes (pid, uid, like_type, date_liked) VALUES ('$pid', '$uid', '1', now())"); //insert new vote
                $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes - 2 WHERE pid = '$pid'");
                if ($sql AND $sql2 AND $sql3) {
                    //all three queries were successful
                    echo "1";
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo "error";
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                //user had voted down but wants to vote up now
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM likes WHERE like_type = '1' AND pid = '$pid' AND uid = '$uid'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); //delete the previous vote
                $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO likes (pid, uid, like_type, date_liked) VALUES ('$pid', '$uid', '0', now())"); //insert new vote
                $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes + 2 WHERE pid = '$pid'");
                if ($sql AND $sql2 AND $sql3) {
                    //all three queries were successful
                    echo "0";
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo "error";
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test2.php

```
<?php
require('db.php');

$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

if ($type == "down") {
    //downvote
    $type = 1;
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO likes (uid, pid, like_type, date_liked) VALUES ('$uid', '$pid', '$type', now())");
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes - 1 WHERE pid = '$pid'");
    if ($sql) {
        echo '1';
        exit;
    }
} else {
    //upvote
    $type = 0;
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO likes (uid, pid, like_type, date_liked) VALUES ('$uid', '$pid', '$type', now())");
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE posts SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE pid = '$pid'");
    if ($sql) {
        echo '1';
        exit;
    }
}
```

These are my pages that are currently used. I plan on moving `test2.php` to `vote.php`.

In my database I have two tables, one to store all the post details including the number of votes. The second table is to store who voted for what post and if it was an upvote or down.

If I could make my system more efficient, please give me tips or recommendations.

Comment: Lots of ways to do that, a quick one is to send the number of votes with the request. Ignore any from that number up or down from the same session.

Comment: One way would be to count the attempts and then simply disable the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick SQL hack: make a unique index on `pid,uid` so that a user can only ever vote once on a post.

ex: `ALTER TABLE vote ADD UNIQUE INDEX pid_uid (pid, uid);`

Quick JS hack: set a variable on submit that you don't clear until the response; if the variable is set, you don't submit the form. Thus, spam clicking will do nothing, since every click after the first will be ignored.

ex:

```
var submitting = false;
function submit_form()
{
    if (!submitting)
    {
        submitting = true;

        // example; insert actual arguments for it to work
        $.post(
            url,
            postData,
            function (data, textStatus)
            {
                submitting = false;
                // handle data here
            },
            "json"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was the most helpful answer

Comment: I ran into a problem, when I set a unique index on `pid, uid` it didn't let other people vote on a post someone has already voted on, and one user could only vote on one post and not multiple posts

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate on the JS hack, it's not really clear to me.

Comment: Did you make the index across BOTH fields, not just one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a lot of improvement to be done.
First you are running open to SQL injection queries. Move that to prepared statement.

Then you can, before insert, check if user already voted for that type, as you already have `uid`, `pid`, and `like_type`. This is server-side.

Client-side your JavaScript could disable clicked button to prevent double click. This will prevent user's to send many requests to the server.

The goal here is let server, PHP, handle the verification if the user already voted to that post, as client -ide is easily manipulated in this case.

Don't forget, move those SQL queries to something safe.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you can only hope to control multiple voting using server-side validation.

Stack Overflow requires the user to sign in to a known account in order to vote, which makes it more difficult (but of course not impossible) for multiple votes.

If you do not require that, the best solution depends on your specific requirements.

A simple, client-only solution is to set a cookie indicating the user has voted.  Disable the appropriate UI element if that cookie is set.  Someone who clears cookies or uses InPrivate style browsing will easily bypass that.  Someone can also write their own client that ignores the cookie.  Perhaps it is sufficient for your requirements.

A naive server-side solution is to allow only one vote per IP address.  I do not recommend this, but include it so you understand why.  Unfortunately, a single user can have multiple IP addresses (just drive down the road on your mobile device and see how many IPs you get), or a single IP can represent multiple physical computers (proxy server).

A solid server-side solution would combine the IP address, user agent, and various aspects of the device to yield a device fingerprint.  This is a complex solution, beyond the needs of most websites (but if you need it, there are a few companies out there that offer device fingerprinting).  Check out https://panopticlick.eff.org/

**Summary**

If you can require the user to log in to vote (like StackOverflow), that will often be the best solution.

If you cannot require that, use device fingerprinting if it is in your budget, otherwise rely on a cookie.  If you do the latter, it may still be worth logging the IP address and user agent of voters so that you can keep an eye out for blatant cheating.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider storing a voter's IP address in a mysql table as an INT once they have voted.

After that either just show them the tally, or provide them the option to undo their vote by voting up/down.

Check out the PHP function ip2long:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Use that to convert the IP address into INT format and store it in your mysql to reference against.

Other Resources:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton